# How to work a button at the same time in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, button

I want to make an application like Noisli website.For example when i tapped rain, it will play but when i press thunder sound it will play to and close the sound with tap again.But it works separately.

I have a function for tap button

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let tag = sender.tag
    PlaySound(filename: sounds[tag])

}

func PlaySound(filename:String){

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "mp3")

            guard url != nil else{ //url not empty
                return
            }

            do{
               audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
                audioPlayer?.play()
            }
            catch{
                print("error")
            }

}
```

Comment: Some advice, instead of having a separate guard statement you should wrap the assignment of url in the guard, so `guard let url ...`. This removes unnecessary code and the url variable is now non optional so you don’t need to force unwrap it. Also in the catch part, print the actual error instead of a hard coded string, `print(error)`. As for your actual question I do not understand what you are asking, maybe you need to clarify it or maybe someone else understands it.

Comment: I am not going to visit some website to understand your question,  you need to ask in such a way that all relevant information to understand the problem is part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `UIControl.State`:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
     sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
     let tag = sender.tag

     if sender.isSelected {
         PlaySound(filename: sounds[tag])
     } else {
         StopSound(filename: sounds[tag])
     }
 }
```